# Is there a maximum number of QTimer instances?

Tags: qt

Is there an upper limit for `QTimer` instances?

I am implementing the game Bomberman and I was thinking each bomb gets its own timer, reaching from 4 to 5 seconds. While there could be up to 8 players, each may have 10 bombs, we are talking roughly about 100 timers.

Should I keep track of the timings by myself or use a timer per bomb?

Please keep in mind that one detonation may trigger others.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any such limits, and it wouldn't make sense either. 100 timers shouldn't be a problem for any platform, supported by Qt. The timer precision however will vary with the platform and the amount of load on the event loop.

I'd say go for the simple solution, and only dig into a more complex solution if you experience performance issues.

Obviously, anything other than a trivial game will implement its own blocking game loop, rather than relying on Qt's events, keeping the time and managing all game objects. Qt and its classes are for application development, and while they could be useful for a simple, trivial game, if you are into game making you really need a game engine, be that a third party or something you make yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a class for the bombs with a QTimer as an attribute.

When you create a bomb automatically the timer starts.

Comment: Now that's helpful /s